# Probability of minimum number of draws required to obtain balls of all three colours is greater than $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Question:A box contains $50$ red balls, $30$ green balls and $20$ blue balls. Suppose balls are
>   drawn successively at random with replacement from the box. Let $N$ denote
>   the minimum number of draws required to obtain balls of all three colours.
>   Compute $P(N > n)$ for all positive integers n.

My attepmt:

I try to find the number of ways to obtain less than $3$ different colouerd balls in $n$ draws. This can happen in following no of ways:

- only red or blue or green balls are obtained with probability $(\frac {5}{10})^n +(\frac {3}{10})^n +(\frac {2}{10})^n$
- only balls of two different colors are obtained with probability 
  $$\sum_{x=0}^n{n\choose x}(\frac {5}{10})^x(\frac {3}{10})^{n-x} + \sum_{x=0}^n {n\choose x}(\frac {5}{10})^x(\frac {2}{10})^{n-x} + \sum_{x=0}^n{n\choose x}(\frac {3}{10})^x(\frac {2}{10})^{n-x}$$
  $$= (\frac {1}{2})^{n} + (\frac {8}{10})^n + (\frac {7}{10})^n$$

And the we sum the probability to get the required answer.

Are my method and calculation correct? Also,if there are any simpler way to do this,you are welcome to mention it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First comment: adding up the sums in case 2 is wrong because the binomial expansion should start at $x=0$ not $x=1$.

Comment: @David sorry for the typo,just edited that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second case includes the first case, in fact, includes it twice.  So you have to subtract the first case once (not add it) to make sure that all cases are counted correctly.  The answer is
$$\eqalign{&\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{n}+\Bigl(\frac{8}{10}\Bigr)^n+\Bigl(\frac{7}{10}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{5}{10}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{3}{10}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{2}{10}\Bigr)^n\cr
  &\qquad\qquad{}=\Bigl(\frac{8}{10}\Bigr)^n+\Bigl(\frac{7}{10}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{3}{10}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{2}{10}\Bigr)^n\ .\cr}$$
This is an example of [inclusion/exclusion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.